# Sign in a User procedurally with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm creating a wizard in rails where a user provides an email, e other information.
At the end of this process the user have to pay something and the a thank you page will appear with a big green button that says: "Go to the dashboard".

The user will receive an email with an auto-generated password for his account but I would like to log him in automatically after he clicks the green button.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the method I need http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in-instance_method any other suggestions?

Comment: No, this is exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in-instance_method

That was the answer